Does the Google Maps timeline show specific location you visited, the time and date, and how long you stayed?
Does the Google Maps timeline show the specific location you visited, the time and date, and how long you stayed?


Will the google maps timeline show specific location you visited and the time and date and how long you stayed

Yes, though sometimes it can be slightly off.
